# log4net %property does not work

Tags: c#, .net, logging, log4net, log4net-configuration

I have a small test project with the following code:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        log4net.GlobalContext.Properties["logFileName"] = "log.txt";
        log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure(new System.IO.FileInfo("log4net.xml"));

        log4net.ILog logger = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger("Tests");

        logger.Debug("Test message");
    }
}
```

My **log4net.xml** config file has the following content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<log4net>
    <appender name="RollingFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
        <file value="%property{logFileName}" />
        <appendToFile value="true" />
        <rollingStyle value="Size" />
        <maxSizeRollBackups value="10" />
        <maximumFileSize value="100KB" />
        <staticLogFileName value="true" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
            <conversionPattern value="%utcdate{ISO8601} [%level][%logger] %message%newline" />
        </layout>
    </appender>
    <root>
        <level value="ALL" />
        <appender-ref ref="RollingFileAppender" />
    </root>
</log4net>
```

My question is why does log4net create file with name **%property{logFileName}** and doesn't substitutes it with **log.txt**?

*log4net* library is taken from NuGet (Id:log4net Version:2.0.3).

Comment: **NEVER** underestimate the power of deleting *bin/obj* folders! Even after doing what the answer suggests, file would still not be generated properly :s

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Please use this in your xml config

```
<file type="log4net.Util.PatternString" value=".\%property{logFileName}" />
```

Comment: Your suggestion solves the problem. Thank you very much!

Comment: Thank you!  I was in despair until I found this and now my config is working.    :-)