# Using registry values in log4net configuration

Tags: c#, configuration, registry, log4net

Is it possible to put a registry value in the log4net filename in the configuration file?
for example, something like this:

```
<log4net>
    <appender name="MainLog" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
      <param name="Encoding" value="Unicode" />
      <param name="File" value="Logs\{Some-Registry-Value}\myLog.log" />
      <param name="AppendToFile" value="false" />
      <maximumFileSize value="50MB" />
      <maxSizeRollBackups value="20" />
      <rollingStyle value="Size"/>
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d %-5p [%t] %logger - %m%n%exception" />
      </layout>
    </appender>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a custom property in your xml so your line would look like:

```
  <param name="File" value="Logs\%property{RegLogPath}\myLog.log" />
```

Then in code, before configuring log4net:

```
     log4net.GlobalContext.Properties["RegLogPath"] = logsFolder;
```

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer doesn't work for me - instead it creates the log files in a directory that is literally named "%property{RegLogPath}"!

Maybe this syntax is not quite right?

**EDIT**:
As noted here: [log4net %property does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30238739/log4net-property-does-not-work)
...it appears the parameter 'type="log4net.Util.PatternString"' (but not the '.\' before '%property') is needed in the config file.

With this change, it works.